# chart.js plugins.register function with outer data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js

How to pass data to chart.plugins.register function? I need to use some data from outside but I cant because it lacks the context:

```
Chart.plugins.register( {
  beforeDraw: function (chart) {
    //code
  }
});
```

I tried `.bind(data)` but it gives errors.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your global variable is `Chart`, you need to declare it in your components.

Under your imports, before your component decorator, do

```
declare var Chart: any;
```

This way, you will gain access to the global variable.

Comment: maybe my question was misleading, I need to have the access to constructor variable, like `public data: Data`

Comment: Yeah that was not clear for me ... And it's still not. You want to pass data to `register`, and you have access to it ? What's stopping you ?

Comment: yes i have access to the data, but when i try to do `Chart.plugins.register.bind(this.data)` it gives me errors of `Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined` so i ask for another way